# Jupyter import error

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have installed jupyter using

```
sudo pip3 install jupyter
```

An then tried to fix some errors with

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter
```

after running `jupyter notebook`, and running some code I receive the following error: `ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'`. Other imports behave similarly. `help('modules')` returns the following output:

```
Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

Usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [options]
A simple dialog based tool for basic configuration of Speech Dispatcher
and problem diagnostics.

ipykernel_launcher.py: error: no such option: -f
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2


/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2889: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

My regular python IDE (PyCharm) works flawlessly. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated greatly. Thank you.